# How to get url of main page with php from within a javascript include?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page with a header include, and the include needs a phone number to change on it ONLY if the filename of the current page contains a certain word.

Normally, for a change that is not within an include, the below code would work.

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'example-match') !== false) 
{
    echo '555-555-5555';
} 
else 
{
    echo '1-800-555-5555';
}
?>
```

However, since the code is in an included file on the page, rather than the original page itself, the server instead is returning the name of that included file.

Example: www.example.com/im-on-this-page.html returns the name of the include the php file is in - www.example.com/header-include.php.

**Is there a way to grab the URL of the page the include is "included on"**, rather than the url of the include, from code that is within the include?

UPDATE:

The file is being included via Javascript, since the page is it being included on is an html file:

```
<script>
$('#Header').load('/includes/header.php');
</script>
```

Comment: This scenario feels a bit strange to me. The `$_SERVER` variable holds _"...an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations."_.Per the documentation, _"The entries in this array are created by the web server."_ An `include` or `require` does not make a separate web request. It's a PHP include so it shouldn't modify these headers at all.

Comment: Instead of include try require and see what happens. Just a suggestion. Although I think that @War10ck is right.

Comment: Ok, I think I may understand what is throwing everyone off. The file is being included via a javascript include.

example:
<script>
  $('#Header').load('/includes/header.php');
 </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of your last comment:

Then it is not an include but a `GET` request to the PHP delivering a JavaScript. And then, the given URL is proper. In order to find out from where the script has been included you may either look for the `referer` header (which is instable) or pass the current file to the script itself:

```
<script> $('#Header')
 .load('/includes/header.php?from=encodeUriComponent("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?php>")'); </script>
```

Within your script, instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` then use `$_GET['from']`

Answer (score 0):

As commentors have mentioned as well. This is incorrect. `$_SERVER` does *not* change for the duration of the script (and includes). Including a file will *not* alter it.

Comment: The file is being included via a javascript include. Perhaps this is what is causing the include to act as though it is a separate file?

Comment: It **is** a separate file and **not** an include from the perspective of PHP.

Comment: @AxelAmthor OP changed the question

Answer (score 0):

A javascript include, meaning it is actually called by the client by an ajax call, and not included on the server before the page is presented.
(you load a page, and then load another page which you "print" somewhere on the first)

a quick and dirty fix would be to write something along these lines on the first php file

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'example-match') !== false) 
{
    echo "<script> var phone_number = '555-555-5555';</script>";
} 
else 
{
    echo "<script> var phone_number = '1-800-555-5555';</script>";
}
?>
```

which will create a variable on the client side, which you then can call from the loaded page as a javascript variable